# Default recipient.email when no checkboxes are selected

Tags: solspace-freeform

I am selecting recipients based on checkbox selections.  This works great except when no checkboxes are selected at all.  How can I check if no selection has been made, and give recipient.email[] a default value if nothing is selected?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a hidden field with the same name before the checkboxes to add the default value.

```
<input type="hidden" class="hidden_recipient" name="recipient_email[]" value="{freeform:recipient_value1}">

<input type="checkbox" class="check_recipient" value="{freeform:recipient_value2}" name="recipient_email[]"/> John Smith
<input type="checkbox" class="check_recipient" value="{freeform:recipient_value3}" name="recipient_email[]"/> Mary Smith
<input type="checkbox" class="check_recipient" value="{freeform:recipient_value4}" name="recipient_email[]"/> Jane Doe
```

Then you could use a little jQuery to clear the value of the hidden field when one of the checkboxes is checked.

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on( "click", function(){
    var count = $("input.check_recipient:checked").length;

    if(count > 0)
    {
        $('.hidden_recipient').val('');
        // You'll need to store the value somewhere in the meantime in case they uncheck again
    }
    else
    {
        // You'll need to restore the original value here
    }
});
```